# how to give username & password in login object

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have added a login object from toolbox ,,now where can give my own username and password in properties window of that login object or i have to write the code in home_frm.aspx.cs file and how can i give that plzzz give me a solution

Thanks,
Churchill

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: i'm using a asp page, the user need to login before accessing any pages...and for that i want to assign a username & password where can i give that

Answer (score 0):

You could validate the username and password entered by the user in the code behind using the [Authenticate event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.authenticate.aspx) to verify user credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get UserName and Password entered by the user, you can use `UserName` and `Password` properties of the login control. If you need to write a custom validation code, use `Authenticate` event handler.

Here you can see some more details:
[The Login Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx#the_login_control)

Answer (score 0):

jst click on the extender that is on the right side of the login you have taken from toolbox. and select convert into template field. thus you will be able to select the textbox inside that login. now simply write the condition in the textchanged event of the tex_username whatever condition of username you want to meet. same thing with password textbox. i have not used this method bt may be it work. just try.